# How to use ESP8266 for wireless communication?

Tags: esp8266

I saw many tutorial explaining how to program ESP8266 but Specifically I didn't get any tutorials explaining how to use with Arduino or any other Microcontroller for Wireless Communication. I had a doubt how could I use it with Arduino for Serial Communication such that I could use with my handset ( using Blynk ) and with my PC.

Comment: http://www.blynk.cc/getting-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very clear on what you are asking but I think you are saying how do you connect an ESP8266 to an Arduino so the Arduino has wireless(WIFI) access.

I'm sure there are tutorials out there so I won't go in to detail (also I don't know the details), but hopefully you will get some better terms to search with.

The basic idea is you connect the serial connection of the ESP8266 to the serial of the Arduino (via a level shifter and connect Tx to Rx).  You then write a series of AT commands to configure the ESP8266 so that what ever is receives over the serial it sends to a TCP endpoint via WIFI (and what it receives is sent to serial).

You can program the ESP via the Arduino IDE, so you could write a 'smarter' version that did all the setup for you, etc.  In fact since the ESP8266 is a faster processor with more RAM you could do a lot more on it.

If you are using an UNO or Nano you might want to look at the software serial library to let you keep the main serial port for debug messages.  If you are using a Mega then you can use one of the secondary serial ports.

Comment: But how could I use it with Blynk ???????

Comment: All described in tutorial I linked. Please read it, ask then more if not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You follow the instructions from blynk.cc/getting-started which include quite simple steps:

> 1 create auth id
>
> 2 download and install blynk library
>
> 3 replace auth id in some example you can find from arduino ide
>
> 4 run code

More details from tutorial.